# Hitting Cloud Dataflow quota limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Suddenly, started getting the following warnings for one of our pipelines:

```
698382 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob  - There were problems getting current job status: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request throttled due to project QPS limit being reached.",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}.
```

The pipeline is reading a lot of data from BigQuery.

Is this a quota exhaustion relating to the BigQuery API (it's not clear from the message)?

Answer (score 2):

Due to a mixup the quota for the RPC used by the `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` to check on the job status was too strictly limited. This has been fixed, and
should not have affected the behavior of a running job. Please let us know
if you continue seeing problems.

You could also avoid making these RPCs by using the `DataflowPipelineRunner`, which won't poll job status after it is submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I am not a Dataflow expert. :)

The [Dataflow quota](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/quotas) is 1000 queries per second (QPS) while the [BigQuery quota](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy) is 100 QPS. I'd suspect you're hitting the BQ limit. Also, the BQ docs do mention `If you make more than 100 requests per second, throttling might occur` and your error seems to reflect that.

If you look at your [BigQuery API use](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/bigquery/usage) do you see 4xx errors?